# <int:pk> not working inside router in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I've the following code inside `urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import SentenceListViewSet, SentenceViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('lists', SentenceListViewSet, basename='SentenceList')
router.register('lists/<int:pk>/sentences/', SentenceViewSet, basename='Sentence')

app_name = 'api_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name='lists')
]
```

It's the second router registry that's causing problem. I get "page not found" if I navigate to `localhost:8000/lists/8/sentences`. However, I can access `localhost:8000/lists/<int:pk>/sentences`.

How can I make DRF capture 8 as a URL parameter instead of int:pk getting treated as a literal part of the URL?

Comment: I think its better its part of the url. Better to be explicit than implicit.

Comment: @Swift Pardon me, but is that a jest?  Well, explicit very well might be better, but in this case, it's caused things to not work: functional and implicit is better than not-working and explicit, don't you think?

Comment: hi use {pk} instead of <int:pk>

Comment: Not a joke in anyway, please see my answer which explains what I mean in a bit more detail. Jest is reserved for social media, not Stackoverflow. Also, if this "doesn't work" please can you provide an error? Because it should work and can work like this as it is set up. You need to be more specific about the issue.

Comment: Its not working because that is not how routers are intended to be used.  You don't specify the key when registering, you use the viewset to define it.  Read the docs at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter.